Spread operator to append List to List or Lists in Dart?
I'm trying to figure out how to use the spread operator to append a List<int> to the end of a List<List<int>>.
I know that I can use the .addAll method, however that doesn't seem to trigger the Riverpod StateNotifier.  At least is didn't with a List<int>.  My display widgets weren't updating unless I used the spread operator to append the new data...
I've tried a bunch of different things to no avail.
void main() {
  listOfLists = [
    [11, 12, 13],
    [21, 22, 23],
    [31, 32, 33],
  ];
  List<int> newData = [41, 42, 43];

//  listOfLists.add(newData);  // This works, but doesn't trigger a widget refresh
//  listOfLists[listOfLists.length - 1] = [...newData]; // This replaces the last List<int> in the List
  listOfLists.last = [...newData]; // This also replaces the last List<int> in the List

  for (var i = 0; i < listOfLists.length; i++) {
    print('Top List#: ${i + 1}');
    print('List Data: ${listOfLists[i]}');
  }
}

I also tried listOfLists[listOfLists.length] = [...newData];, but it throws an exception during runtime.
The fact that I can replace the last list seems to imply that it should be doable with the right syntax.

I think I figured it out: listOfLists = [...listOfLists, newData];

It also seems like I can use the List methods in the StateNotifier as long as I put state = [...state]; at eh end to trigger the refresh.  Anything wrong with doing that?

Avoid legacy riverpod tools. In brief, avoid legacy ChangeNotifier, StateNotifier (and their providers) and StateProvider.  Use only Provider, FutureProvider, StreamProvider, and Notifier, AsyncNotifier, StreamNotifier (and their providers).

The .add method directly modifies the list but doesn't trigger a state change in RiverPod or other state management solutions because it doesn't change the list reference, only its content. To trigger a state change, you need to create a new list. In the example, replace .add with:
final listProvider = StateNotifierProvider<ListNotifier, List<List<int>>>((ref) {
  return ListNotifier();
});

class ListNotifier extends StateNotifier<List<List<int>>> {
  ListNotifier() : super([]);

  void addList(List<int> newList) {
    state = [...state, newList];
  }
}

This copies the existing list and adds the new list, creating a new list reference. This way, RiverPod detects the state change and updates the UI.

Yes, that is what I have now, thanks!  I guess I need to migrate it though since those are apparently legacy.  How would you remove a specific sublist from the main list the state is controlling?  What would the method in the StateNotifier look like for that?

Also, can you do use methods like the .add method and just include a state = [...state]; at the end of the method?

It worked in the main function, however, when I put it into the Notifier (upgraded from StateNotifier), I'm getting the list that was just added in every list of lists.  i.e. every value at 'j' is the same for every 'i' in ref.watch(listProvider)[i][j].

Got it to work.  It worked with hard-coded lists, but when I tried to use generated lists, it was doing as above.  I had to copy the List<int> I was sending to a new list as follows: List<int> sendList = [...generatedList]; and ref.read(listProvider.Notifier).addList(sendList);
